# "бігборд" чи "білборд"?

Tags: вживання-слів

В чому різниця між «*бігборд*» та «*білборд*»? Ні в Академічному, ні в орфографічному словникові не знайшла жодного з цих слів. Але в повсякденному житті зустрічала обидва варіанти. То як правильно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Англійською воно зветься [«billboard»](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=billboard&client=opera&hs=KW7&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEktuM3sbZAhVCBSwKHXmuBhAQ_AUICigB&biw=1024&bih=640) (від «bill» (оголошення, заява) + «board» (дошка)), тож і українською буде відповідно «білборд».

Answer (score 4):

Зі «Словника української мови» в 20 томах (під егідою Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду Національної академії наук України):

> **[БІГБО́РД](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=183632&page=159)**, *а*, *ч*. Те саме, що **білбо́рд**. <…>
>
> ---
>
> **[БІЛБО́РД](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=196384&page=162)**, *а*, *ч*.
>   Рекламний щит великих розмірів, який встановлюється перев. вздовж вулиць і доріг. <…>